# Archimedean spiral from curvature

Tags: differential-equations, differential-geometry

I am trying to reconstruct an Archimedean spiral from its curvature

$$\kappa (\text{s$\_$})\text{:=}\frac{s^2+2}{\left(s^2+1\right)^{3/2}};$$

eqns:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 t'(s)=\frac{\left(s^2+2\right) n(s)}{\left(s^2+1\right)^{3/2}} \\
 n'(s)=-\frac{\left(s^2+2\right) t(s)}{\left(s^2+1\right)^{3/2}} \\
 r'(s)=t(s) \\
 t(0)=\{1,0\} \\
 n(0)=\{0,1\} \\
 r(0)=\{0,0\} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

```
eqns = {(t^\[Prime])[s]==((2+s^2) n[s])/(1+s^2)^(3/2),(n^\[Prime])[s]==-(((2+s^2) t[s])/(1+s^2)^(3/2)),(r^\[Prime])[s]==t[s],t[0]=={1,0},n[0]=={0,1},r[0]=={0,0}}

sol = First@NDSolve[eqns, {r, t, n}, {s, 0, 64 2 \[Pi]}]
```

This gives a solution:

[image]

plotting the result:

```
With[{s1=(r/.sol)["Domain"][[1,1]],s2=(r/.sol)["Domain"][[1,2]]},

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[r[s]/.sol],{s,s1,s2},PlotRange->30{{-1,1},{-1,1}},AspectRatio->Automatic]]
```

gives this obviously non archimedean spiral:

[image]

What ist going wrong here?

Any hints wellcome

Comment: Incomplete info. You have not provided the definition of `eqns`.

Comment: Hi Henrik, cant you see them?
Below the curvature there are 3 equations plus 3 initial conditions ... eqns= ...

Comment: I can see them but I cannot _copy_ them. And I am too lazy to retype them (like virtually every other user here). So, what is not copyable does not exist.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your subtle comment
eqns ready for copy/paste

Comment: Hm. Weird. What _Mathematica_ returns to me looks pretty much like an Archimedian spiral. Please try to restart the kernel (e.g. by executing `Exit`) and try again.

Comment: Due to some confusion when editing the question I gave a curvature with an different equation which in deed looks like an archimedean but it is just an approximate one, now the correct curvature is inside the question and this surprisingly gives the ugli non achimedean plot as can bee seen. sorry for the confusion now the correct archimedean curvature gives the wrong spiral.

Comment: Are you sure your formula for curvature is correct? I believe yours is curvature as function of the polar angle rather than of the arclength.

Comment: Yes that is true. I think you want to tell me that the frenet-serret formalism only works for the arclength parametrization? Is that the case? Any chance to get the curvature based on the arclength from the angle based parametrization?

Comment: Precisely - it only works for the arclength. You need to correct the equations using $\frac{df}{ds}=\frac{df}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{ds}$ for $f=r,t,n$, where (in your case) $\frac{d\theta}{ds}=\frac1{\sqrt{1+\theta^2}}$

Comment: The equations will take form$$\begin{array}{rl}t'(\theta)&=\frac{2+\theta^2}{1+\theta^2}n(\theta),\\n'(\theta)&=-\frac{2+\theta^2}{1+\theta^2}t(\theta),\\r'(\theta)&=\sqrt{1+\theta^2}t(\theta)\end{array}$$

Comment: hmmmm this gives a nice archimedean looking spiral.
Is this exact - suppose we could exactly solve the differential equations?

Comment: Well post factum we know that $r(\theta)=(\theta\cos(\theta),\theta\sin(\theta))$ (which then uniquely determines $t$ and $n$) satisfies the system

Comment: At any rate, eliminating $t$ and $n$ gives the equation $(2+\theta^2)r'''=2\theta r''-(6+\theta^2)r'$. Its general solution (in complex form) is $C_0+C_1\theta e^{i\theta}+C_2i\theta e^{-i\theta}$

Comment: Ok, figure it out how the reparamtrization works in this case. Surprisingly for me the the numerical solution (NDSolve) still is not arclength paramterized which can be seen by evaluating the result (InterpolatingFunction) at equidistant values which results in increasingly separated points.

Comment: With equally spaced values of the angular parameter, points must be at equal radial angles rather than arc length distances from each other.

Comment: Sorry for my limited understanding but didn't we reparametrize the curve by arclength?
To my simple understanding the curve isn't paramtrized by angle any more?
We obviously could apply the frenet-serret formalism which seemingly worked.

Comment: If I am not confusing things, the parameter $\theta$ is the polar angle. We applied the formalism but reexpressed everything in terms of $\theta$, using that derivative of arclength by $\theta$ is $\sqrt{1+\theta^2}$ in this case. If we would like to parametrize by arclength, we should substitute in the curvature formula the value of $\theta$ expressed by arclength, i. e. solve $\theta$ from $s=\frac12(\operatorname{arcsinh}(\theta)+\theta\sqrt{1+\theta^2})$. I don't know any explicit expression for that.

Comment: Another possibility: in your equations, use $\kappa(s)=\frac{\theta(s)^2+2}{(\theta(s)^2+1)^{\frac32}}$ and add one more equation $\theta'(s)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+\theta(s)^2}}$

Answer (score 9):

Ok, thanks to მამუკა ჯიბლაძე I got the following solution:

```
Archimedean[θ_]:=θ{Cos@θ,Sin@θ}
ac[θ_]:=ArcCurvature[Archimedean[θ],θ]//Simplify
l[θ_]:=Archimedean[θ]//Sqrt[Total[D[#,θ]^2]]&//Simplify

Archimedean[θ]
ac[θ]
l[θ]
```

this gives the archimedean, it's curvature and the arclength derivative
$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \{\theta  \cos (\theta ),\theta  \sin (\theta )\} \\
 \frac{\theta ^2+2}{\left(\theta ^2+1\right)^{3/2}} \\
 \sqrt{\theta ^2+1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

here are the (differential) equations to be solved
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \kappa (s)=\frac{\theta (s)^2+2}{\left(\theta (s)^2+1\right)^{3/2}} \\
 \theta '(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\theta (s)^2+1}} \\
 t'(s)=n(s) \kappa (s) \\
 n'(s)=-t(s)\kappa (s) \\
 r'(s)=t(s) \\
 t(0)=\{1,0\} \\
 n(0)=\{0,1\} \\
 r(0)=\{0,0\} \\
 \theta (0)=0 \\
\end{array}
$$

now let's solve and plot a perfect (with respect to NDSolve) archimedean with perfectly equal arclength-spaced points.

```
eqns = {
   κ[s] == ((2 + θ[s]^2)/(1 + θ[s]^2)^(3/2)),
   θ'[s] == 1/Sqrt[1 + θ[s]^2],
   t'[s] == κ[s] n[s],
   n'[s] == -κ[s] t[s],
   r'[s] == t[s],
   t[0] == {1, 0},
   n[0] == {0, 1},
   r[0] == {0, 0},
   θ[0] == 0
   };

sol = First@NDSolve[eqns, {r, t, n, θ, κ}, {s, 0, 200}]
With[{sr = (r /. sol)["Domain"][[1]]}, 
  Table[Evaluate[r[s] /. sol], {s, sr[[1]], sr[[2]], 1}]] // 
 ListPlot[#, AspectRatio -> Automatic] &
```

[image]